# html css code to display multiple tables horizontally or in a single row

Tags: html, css

I have created a table which loops from a database. Now **I need to display this multiple table in a single row.** Currently the loop display tables in columns. **Please can someone suggest how to write the markup, so that it generates and displays table data in a single row?**

For example, if there are 10 tables loops from the database, then there should be 10 cells in a single table row. The table should not contain anything below that row. It's ok for a horizontal scrollbar to display in the event that the table is longer than the screen width.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">First Name</th>     


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">James</td>  

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The</td>
          <td>Tick</td>              
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: `<tr>` tags create rows, if you only want one row, just use one of them. `<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>` moving the `<tr>` outside of any loop you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Table inside table is not valid. You have to add table row then add all the tables under each table columns like below.

```
  <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <tr>
       <td>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">First Name</th>   
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">James</td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>The</td>
                  <td>Tick</td>              
               </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
         Your Second Table Goes here..
      </td> 
      <td>
         Your Third Table Goes here and so on.
      </td>  
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want the table shown above to be repeated multiple times such and to appear side by side in a single row.

What I would do is add the CSS property `display: inline-table` (use a class) to the relevant tables.

See the following example:

```css
.tablePanel {
  width: 300%;
  word-break: nowrap;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
 }
.tablePanel table {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  display: inline-table;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tablePanel">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">First Name</th>     


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">James</td>  

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The</td>
          <td>Tick</td>              
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
     <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">First Name</th>     


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">James</td>  

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The</td>
          <td>Tick</td>              
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">First Name</th>     


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">James</td>  

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The</td>
          <td>Tick</td>              
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">First Name</th>     


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">James</td>  

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The</td>
          <td>Tick</td>              
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```